# react native - eslint give too much errors

Tags: react-native, eslint

I'm not that good coding with react native,
but I keep getting errors from eslint,

for example:

```
 {
        this.state.markers.map(marker => (
          <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={{longitude: marker.longitude, latitude: marker.latitude}}
            title={marker.title}
            description={marker.info}>
          </MapView.Marker>
        ))
      }
```

eslint provides red line error with message: `Missing "key" prop for element in iteratoreslintreact/jsx-key`

it makes me hesitate that the code is wrong.

and many more errors with props.

why is that? the map works well, and sometimes i use this.props and also get errors.

any alternative for eslint or its the best?

im using vscode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [eslint: Missing "key" prop for element in iterator (react/jsx-key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54401481/eslint-missing-key-prop-for-element-in-iterator-react-jsx-key)

Comment: it fixed in this map iteration, but for example I have class with navigation and it works when i write this.props.navigation and somehow I receive there red line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a key property for arrays of components so that react can properly detect that the object has changed. If you don't, react just compares the previous and current object references which can lead to some unexpected behavior and performance issues.
If your marker items had a name property, you could do this:

```
{
        this.state.markers.map(marker => (
          <MapView.Marker
            key={marker.name}
            coordinate={{longitude: marker.longitude, latitude: marker.latitude}}
            title={marker.title}
            description={marker.info}>
          </MapView.Marker>
        ))
}
```