# Error: Missing "key" prop for element in iterator react/jsx-key

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Error: Missing "key" prop for element in iterator  react/jsx-key
info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules?

```
return (
<div>
  <div>
    <BreadcrumbBlogs />
  </div>
  <div className={styles.container}>
    <div className={styles.blogblock}>
      {newsposts.slice(0, 6).map((post) => (
        <div className={styles.blogcontent} key={post.id}>
          <Image
            src={post.jetpack_featured_media_url}
            width={600}
            height={400}
            alt="thumbnail"
          ></Image>
          <Link href={`${post.id}`} className={styles.blogcolumn}>
            <div
              className={styles.blogtitile}
              dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.title.rendered }}
            ></div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

);

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SVpZ.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [eslint: Missing "key" prop for element in iterator (react/jsx-key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54401481/eslint-missing-key-prop-for-element-in-iterator-react-jsx-key)

Comment: Add key here `<div className={styles.blogcontent} key={post.id}>` and remove from `Link` tag. `key` attribute needs to be added for parent element inside `map` .

Comment: Your outer div needs a key attribute See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Can you share the `newsposts` array format ?

Comment: Please check the screenshot above, Thanks

Comment: please, leave your code in the question as is, applying the answer to your code only causes confusion and doesn't help future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In React, when you want to create multiple components, you have to provide a "key" for every child component, and that key has to be a unique value.

So, in order to solve that problem, add the key prop to the div

```
<div className={styles.blogcontent} key={post.id}>
```

In case you don't have an id, you can use anything that is unique (like the array index for example).

Comment: Tried this but not working, please check the screenshot above. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, add `key={post.id}` to your `div` element instead of the `Link` element. The ESLint rule in this case is providing valuable feedback so I wouldn’t disable it.

Comment: Tried this but not working, please check the screenshot above. Thanks